# Не сработало событие клика в jquery, почему?

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
$(document).on("click", ".calendar li.active a", function() {
alert('ok');
});
```

Клик по элементу **li** HTML списка **UL**:

```
<li class="active" data-original-title="1 записей"><a href="#" type="news" datastart="1411948800" dataend="1412035200" class="active">29</a></li>
```

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, проверьте самое очевидное: находится ли элемент `li.active a` внутри `.calendar`.  
Ваш пример работает: http://jsfiddle.net/hfz80gug/

Comment: Оказалось, все дело в `$(document)...`, но без него нельзя. Как быть?
____

Да, проверку сделал. Все дело в конструкции, как указал выше. Есть альтернативы ей? Это для того, чтобы сработал клик по элементу, созданному динамически на странице.

Comment: Вешайте событие на `body`, чем не вариант? http://jsfiddle.net/hfz80gug/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вешайте событие при создании этого динамического элемента, а не при загрузке страницы

```
$('li.active a').click(function(){
    alert(1);
});
```